# Dissolving tool is doing really stupid stuff

Tags: modeling, edges, faces

I'm trying to model a Star Destroyer, from Star Wars. If you look up a picture of it, you'll notice that there are indentations along the sides where mechanical looking things and whatnot reside. I'm trying to recreate those by insetting a face, which adds this annoying little face:

[image]

However, on trying to dissolve the edges to get rid of it, it does not "merge faces" as the tool description says, it deletes a ton of unrelated edges, giving me this:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you explain better you issue, for better understanding?

Comment: When I try to dissolve a face that was added by insetting a different face, it deletes most of the inside of this mesh. I don't understand why this is.

Comment: dissolve vertices instead of faces, and also unselect the vertices from the edges, just select the inside ones.